# Simple Bash Script File Copy

Tags: bash

I am having trouble with a simple grading script I am writing.  I have a directory called HW5 containing a folder for each student in the class.  From my current directory, which contains the HW5 folder, I would like to copy all files starting with the word mondial, to each of the students' folders. My script runs but does not copy any of the files over.  Any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                         

for file in ./HW5; do
    if [ -d $file ]; then
        cp ./mondial.* ./$file;
    fi
done
```

Thanks,

Comment: This iterates once with the `$file` value as `./HW5`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first loop was executing only once, with `file` equal `./HW5`. Add the star to actually select the files or directories inside it.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                         

for file in ./HW5/*; do
  if [ -d "$file" ]; then
    cp ./mondial.* ./"$file"
  fi
done
```

As suggested by Mark Reed, this can be simplified:

```
for file in ./HW5/*/; do 
  cp ./mondial.* ./"$file"
done
```

Comment: Or just use  `for file in ./HW5/*/;` and skip the `-d` test.

Comment: This breaks on directories that contain spaces and is not properly indented. My edit to fix the former was reverted.

Comment: As @jordanm indicates, the expansions of `$file` should be quoted: `cp ./mondial.* ./"$file"`, for instance.

Comment: OK, I added the quotes. I think @jordanm was editing the answer at the same time as I was, and his edit got lost.

Comment: Or a one-liner: `echo ./HW5/*/ | xargs -n 1 cp ./mondial/*`

Comment: Also, since `file` already has `./` in its value, putting `./` in front of it is redundant.  The `cp` ends up being `cp ./mondial.* ././HW5/whatever/`.

Comment: @RichardPump that also breaks for directory names containing spaces.

Comment: `find ./HW5 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 cp mondial/*` (thank you @MarkReed for pointing out the problem, jumped a gun there).